# Android ADK Licenses have not been accepted build-tools:34

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I have Android Studio installed along with the CLI tools. I have run `.\sdkmanager --licenses` within the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin directory` and it shows as all licenses accepted.

In my environment variables, in PATH I have the following configured:
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`

When trying to run the Android emulator for my react-native project I am getting the following errors:

```
Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location 

'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator' (Expected 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator')
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 34 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 34 not accepted.
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
        build-tools;34.0.0 Android SDK Build-Tools 34
        platforms;android-34 Android SDK Platform 34
     To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
     All licenses can be accepted using the SDK manager command line tool:
     SDK manager --licenses
     Or, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

     Using Android SDK: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
```

I am confused by two things which I cannot find a solution to:

1. emulator inconsistent location - I'm not sure why it is throwing this error?
2. licenses not accepted - these show as accepted when running `sdkmanager --licenses` in the directory and the paths referenced in the logs are all correct according to where I ran the command and can see the installed packages

How can I rectify these errors?